# Обработка формы. Как обработать инпут?

Tags: php, формы

Всем привет! Есть такая задача:

Дан массив с вопросами и правильными ответами. Реализуйте тест: выведите на экран все вопросы, под каждым инпут. Пользователь читает вопрос, пишет свой ответ в инпут. Когда вопросы заканчиваются - он жмет на кнопку, страница обновляется и вместо инпутов под вопросами появляется сообщение вида: 'ваш ответ: ... верно!' или 'ваш ответ: ... неверно!

Моя реализация примерно такая:

```
$arr = ['Question 1' => '2'];

function createInput() {
    return '<input type="text" name="input-text">';
}

foreach ($arr as $key => $elem) {
    echo $key . '<br>';
    echo createInput();
}

if (!empty($_REQUEST)) {
    if ($_REQUEST['input-text'] == $elem) {
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
}
```

Это просто маленький пример. Ответ 'true' или 'false' не выходит. Подскижите что тут можно сделать?

Comment: Дурацкий вопрос: а сколько ответов проверяет код проверки?

Comment: Для начала - прочтите [Работа с формами в PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: Как понять сколько ответов? Он проверят первый элемент массива.

Comment: А почему первый если надо проверять все? Подсказка: проверку тоже надо делать в цикле.

Comment: И еще одна подсказка: в скрипт вейчас приходит только один ответ, потому что имя поля всегда одно и то же. А должны быть разные